To repair a hole in vinyl siding, can I patch in a piece or do I replace the whole plank?
I discovered a hole in the siding of my garage.  It's too big to patch (probably about 2" or 4cm) but it's on the bottom row of a seldom used side of the garage, currently behind my wife's flowers and behind where the A/C compressor will eventually go.  I understand the replacement piece won't exactly match.  Can I get away with cutting the damage out and replacing it with a left over scrap of the same siding, or should I replace the whole plank?

Vinyl siding comes from the factory as pre-cut "patch" pieces that are 12 feet long.
The only reasons to put a longer piece in is to replace many damaged spots in one shot or to ensure that seams don't line up from one row to the next.
A couple of things to keep in mind as you're installing your patch:

Be sure to overlap ~2" at each end
Don't nail it tight. Even with a short patch piece, you don't want it warping in the heat of summer.
Be sure that the overlaps follow the overlap pattern of the rest of the siding.

Vinyl siding is usually installed all from one end of the wall to the other so that all the overlaps are the same. Usually the overlap direction is chosen to minimize visibility of the overlap from either the street, or from the view most commonly seen by the house occupants.
I'm about to start siding an addition to my house. There will be an inside corner, so all the siding will start at the inside corner and go toward the outside corners. That way, when looking at it, the overlaps will (somewhat) disappear because you won't be seeing the edges.




The single planks I was referring to are the 12' long pieces that came in the box.  I would call those "full planks" and not "patches."  The "patch" I'm talking about is a piece of scrap that's about 6" long.

That's my point, @Duston. Whether you're putting on a 6" or 144" piece doesn't really matter. They install the same way. You use the same techniques/cautions for both. The only real concern is the aesthetics of having two seams that close together. If it doesn't bother you to have seams close together (say they're going to be hidden behind plants or AC units), then go for it.  If it's right by the front stairs and you're going to see it daily and it'll bother you, replace the whole 12' section.
